# Imported meshes can't be picked deterministically

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, babylonjs

I've got grid of cylinder meshes created simply by

```
var tile = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateCylinder("tile-" + i, { tessellation: 6, height: 0.1 }, scene);
```

then I have following event callback

```
window.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    // try to pick an object
    var pickResult = scene.pick(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
    if (pickResult.pickedMesh != null){
         alert(pickResult.pickedMesh.name)
});
```

Then `mouse-click` on one of `tiles` raises `message box` with correct tile name.

When I add some new meshes (3D model inside `.babylon` file) by

```
var house;
BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh("", "../Content/"
                              , "house.babylon"
                              , scene
                              , function (newMeshes) 
                                { house = newMeshes[0]; });
```

For better imagination it's texture of house created from four different meshes which is placed over `grid` of `cylinder` tiles.

It's displayed fine but when `mouse-click` it too much often behave as it would totally ignore there is such a mesh and so `pickResult.pickedMesh` is either `null` or `pickResult.pickedMesh.name` points to tile underlaying my imported mesh in point I've clicked.

Just approximately `5%` of mesh area corresponds properly to `mouse-clicks` (let's say in middle of roof, in middle of walls).

I've tried playing with setting some virtual (hidden) `house.parent` `mesh` for that which would not be created by importing meshes but seems as dead end.

Are you aware about some way how enforce that `scene.pick(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);` would respect mesh hierarchy and would consider all visible parts of overlaying texture?

Just for completeness I'm working with middle part of this [3D](https://clara.io/view/bf4a29e2-500a-4de2-866b-ac9bf9425b3d) model (removed left and right house from that).

EDIT: Demo on [BabylonJS playground](http://babylonjs-playground.com/#V26CZB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try change

```
var pickResult = scene.pick(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
```

to

```
var pickResult = scene.pick(scene.pointerX, scene.pointerY);
```

as `evt` corresponds to whole page.